# Emulate ttyS0 on Ubuntu 22 or link it to ttyUSB0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udev, port, socat

I have a JAVA code that checks if ttyS0 is present. I dont have a serial port, so Im getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  Error opening "/dev/ttyS0"
  tcgetattr(): Input/output error
    at com.sun.comm.LinuxDriver.getCommPort(LinuxDriver.java:66)
    at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.open(CommPortIdentifier.java:369)
    at sport.<init>(sport.java:41)
    at srt.main(srt.java:152)
```

How do I emulate this port, eg. using `socat` or `screen` or anything else? I tried a few things I found, but the code still cant find it.

This is what is not working for me (ttyS0 does not show when I do `sudo dmesg | grep tty`):

```
tio /dev/ttyS0
sudo busybox microcom -t 2400 /dev/ttyS0
socat PTY,link=ttyS0,raw,echo=0 -
sudo socat stty -f /dev/ttys0 2400
```

Or maybe there is a way to link ttyS0 to ttyUSB0? This would also do, since our device is connected to USB via USB/RS232 adapter.

Comment: You can simply create a symlink from ttyS0 to ttyUSB0.

Comment: @larsks It worked! I didnt expected it to be so easy, thank you.